# How can I read the content of the User-Parameters attribute of an Active Directory Object?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to extract some information from an Active Directory object, such as the profile path or if the user is locked out or not.

I can see these information are saved inside the **[User-Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680847.aspx)** attribute of the Active Directory object, but the value of this attribute is a mangled string of incomprehensible characters:

[image: An example of a value of the User-Parameters attribute.]

I can see that [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27814791) had the same problem, but there's not clear solution on how to parse that attribute.

How can I extract the data I need while maintaining my sanity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [User-Parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160336/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680847.aspx) attribute value is quite… *particular*.

While the attribute definition says that the value is a [Unicode string](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160501/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684455.aspx), the reality is a little more complex: the value is a binary payload of mixed text and binary data encoded using a couple of "algorithms" and then *casted* to a Unicode string — that's why you see junk characters, these character are actually pure binary data displayed as a string.

There are many articles on the internet on how to decode this value, but most of them are either wrong or manage to decode the value using a wrong procedure (which, while yielding correct data in their examples, could break at any time).

Examples of such articles are:

- [Reading and writing the Terminal Server userParameters binary blob in Active Directory](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160523/https://daduke.org/linux/userparameters.html) — the decoding algorithm is wrong, see below on how it works;
- [Microsoft Active Directory: UserParameters Header](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160558/https://00laboratories.com/resources/code/c-sharp/microsoft-active-directory-userparameters-header) — uses the same wrong decoding algorithm as the previous one and is needlessly complicated;
- and [VB.NET Decode AD UserParameters Attribute Values](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160655/https://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2014/08/24/vb-net-decode-ad-userparameters-attribute-values/) — this *seems* to get it right, but I'm not skilled enough in VB to validate the code.

How the data is encoded is defined in the [Terminal Services Terminal Server Runtime Interface Protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160951/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc248570.aspx) documentation.

In particular you're looking for:

- the [userParameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160836/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635189.aspx) document, which describes the overall structure of the binary payload;
- the [TSProperty](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160911/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635169.aspx) document, which describes the structure of the properties contained in the payload;
- and the [Encoding PropValue Field in TSProperty Structure](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161013/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635243.aspx) document, which explains how the value of the properties contained in the payload is encoded.

Optionally you can have a look to the [Encoding/Decoding Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161204/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635403.aspx) for a (really) terse example on how to decode the properties values.

If you're still with me, didn't lose your sanity, summoned Cthulhu or set on fire whoever inside Microsoft ever thought that doing something like this was a good idea, let's proceed to write the code to parse and extract the data.

> Per me si va ne la città dolente,
>   per me si va ne l'etterno dolore,
>   per me si va tra la perduta gente.
>   […]
>   Lasciate ogni speranza, voi ch'entrate.
>
> *— Dante Alighieri, Divina Commedia, Inferno, Canto III*

*(There's a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example linked at the end of the answer for those who are too impatient to read everything.)*

## Step 1 — Getting the attribute value

You can get the value through either the System.DirectoryServices (usually calles "S.DS") or System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (usually called "S.DS.P") libraries. If you need some help on how these libraries work you can read the [Using System.DirectoryServices to Search the Active Directory](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161517/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx) and [Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161756/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx) articles.

If you are a .NET Framework user, these are your usual GAC assemblies so you'll have to add them as you always do.

If you are a .NET Core user, rejoice! Both libraries have been released on NuGet — albeit as a pre-release — on 2017-11-15, so you too can query Active Directory now! Go fetch them: [System.DirectoryServices](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161853/https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices/), [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161916/https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.Protocols/).

> **Nota bene:** The code in this answer has been written for a .NET Core 2.0 target, if you're not using .NET Core you probably have to adjust the code slightly; these changes however should be small and easy as the Core and non-Core version of the libraries are very similar.

Here we're reading the attribute using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols:

```
var ldapDirectoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(
  "domain-controller.example.com",
  389,
  true,
  false);

var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(
  "alice@example.com",
  "p@sSw0rd",
  "example.com");

var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(
  ldapDirectoryIdentifier,
  networkCredential,
  AuthType.Kerberos);

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
  "DC=example,DC=com",
  "(objectClass=user)",
  SearchScope.Subtree,
  "userParameters");

// WARNING
// If the parameters of either LdapDirectoryIdentifier or NetworkCredential are wrong
// (e.g. invalid credentials) you'll get an exception here.
var searchResponse = (SearchResponse) ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

foreach (SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry in searchResponse.Entries)
{
  // WARNING
  // This WILL throw an exception when used on an object where the attribute is missing.
  // You should really check that the attribute exists and has exactly one value.
  // I skipped that for brevity, you should not.
  var directoryAttribute = searchResultEntry.Attributes["userParameters"];
  var attributeValue = (string) directoryAttribute[0];
}
```

## Step 2 — Define what the attribute contains

Now that we have the value of the attribute, we need something to hold the values it contains.

First of all, we need some enums.

The first one is the `CtxCfgFlags1` enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum CtxCfgFlags1 : uint
{
  Undefined1 = 0x00000000,
  Undefined2 = 0x00000001,
  Undefined3 = 0x00000002,
  DisableCam = 0x00000004,
  WallpaperDisabled = 0x00000008,
  DisableExe = 0x00000010,
  DisableClip = 0x00000020,
  DisableLpt = 0x00000040,
  DisableCcm = 0x00000080,
  DisableCdm = 0x00000100,
  DisableCpm = 0x00000200,
  UseDefaultGina = 0x00000400,
  HomeDirectoryMapRoot = 0x00000800,
  DisableEncryption = 0x00001000,
  ForceClientLptDef = 0x00002000,
  AutoClientLpts = 0x00004000,
  AutoClientDrives = 0x00008000,
  LogonDisabled = 0x00010000,
  ReconnectSame = 0x00020000,
  ResetBroken = 0x00040000,
  PromptForPassword = 0x00080000,
  InheritSecurity = 0x00100000,
  InheritAutoClient = 0x00200000,
  InheritMaxIdleTime = 0x00400000,
  InheritMaxdisconnectionTime = 0x00800000,
  InheritMaxsessionTime = 0x01000000,
  InheritShadow = 0x02000000,
  InheritCallbackNumber = 0x04000000,
  InheritCallback = 0x08000000,
  Undefined4 = 0x10000000,
  Undefined5 = 0x20000000,
  Undefined6 = 0x40000000,
  Undefined7 = 0x80000000
}
```

> **Nota bene:** The values defined in [TSProperty](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160911/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635169.aspx) are missing a couple of entries, the ones named `Undefined*`; these values are not listed in the definition but have been observed in the wild, if you don't define them your flag enum will break and won't be displayed nicely when you look at it through the debugger or `.ToString()`.

The second one is the `CtxShadow` enum:

```
public enum CtxShadow : uint
{
  Disable = 0x00000000,
  EnableInputNotify = 0x00000001,
  EnableInputNoNotify = 0x00000002,
  EnableNoInputNotify = 0x00000003,
  EnableNoInputNoNotify = 0x00000004
}
```

Now we can define the class to hold the properties:

```
public class UserParameters
{
  public uint? CtxCfgPresent { get; set; }
  public CtxCfgFlags1? CtxCfgFlags1 { get; set; }
  public uint? CtxCallBack { get; set; }
  public uint? CtxKeyboardLayout { get; set; }
  public byte? CtxMinEncryptionLevel { get; set; }
  public uint? CtxNwLogonServer { get; set; }
  public string CtxWfHomeDir { get; set; }
  public string CtxWfHomeDirDrive { get; set; }
  public string CtxInitialProgram { get; set; }
  public uint? CtxMaxConnectionTime { get; set; }
  public uint? CtxMaxDisconnectionTime { get; set; }
  public uint? CtxMaxIdleTime { get; set; }
  public string CtxWfProfilePath { get; set; }
  public CtxShadow? CtxShadow { get; set; }
  public string CtxWorkDirectory { get; set; }
  public string CtxCallbackNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Nothing fancy here, these are simply the properties defined in the [TSProperty](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160911/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635169.aspx) document.

## Step 3 — Parse the payload

Now it's time to decode the payload contained inside the value of the attribute.

The [userParameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160836/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635189.aspx) and [TSProperty](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104160911/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635169.aspx) documents define the structure of the payload.

The payload is divided in two main sections: a "header" section and a "data" section.

The "header" section contains

- an undocumented 96 bytes byte array "ReservedData" subsection which will be treated as a black-box;
- a 2 bytes Unicode string "Signature" which should be used as a "control value";
- and a 2 bytes unsigned integer "TSPropertyCount" holding how many properties the payload contains.

The "data" section is an unseparated contiguous list of properties, each property contains

- a 2 bytes unsigned integer "NameLength" holding the length in bytes of the name of the property;
- a 2 bytes unsigned integer "ValueLength" holding the length bytes of the value of the property;
- a 2 bytes unsigned integer "Type" holding the type of the property;
- a variable-length Unicode string "PropName" holding the name of the property;
- a variable-length double-ASCII-encoded byte array "PropValue" holding the value of the property;

The length of the "PropName" and "PropValue" fields must be obtained from the "NameLength" and "ValueLength" fields respectively.

Wait. "double-ASCII-encoded"? What's that?

Each property can have as a value either a byte, a uint, or an ASCII string. When saved the value of the property is converted to its binary representation, then the byte-array of the binary representation is converted to it hexadecimal string representation, then each character of the hexadecimal string representation is converted to its binary representation and then stored.

For posterity, this is how the encoding algorithm is explained by Microsoft:

> To create the encoded binary BLOB for the PropValue field, for each byte of the input create its ASCII-encoded hexadecimal representation and place this representation in 2 consecutive bytes of the output buffer, the most significant hexadecimal digit first followed by the least significant hexadecimal digit.
>
> For example, if the input byte contains the ASCII representation of character 'A', the resulting output will be a sequence of two ASCII characters: character '4' followed by character '1' because the hexadecimal representation of a byte that contains the ASCII character 'A' is 41.
>
> Hence, the output buffer corresponding to the input buffer byte containing character 'A' will be a sequence of 2 bytes whose hexadecimal representations are 34 and 31.
>
> As another example, the input buffer containing the ASCII string "ABCDE\0" would be encoded into the ASCII string "414243444500" (without the terminating 0), which is the same as a sequence of 12 bytes whose hexadecimal representations are 34, 31, 34, 32, 34, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 30, and 30.

Simple, yes?

Let's break down the process step-by-step.

First of all, we need to prepare a container for the properties and the convert the data to a more manageable form:

```
var userParameters = new UserParameters();
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(attributeValue);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode, true);
```

Why are we using `MemoryStream` and `BinaryReader`? Because it's really, *really* easier to use: instead of having to keep track of the offset where we should start to read from as we gradually proceed, we can simply call `.ReadBytes(int)` which is *consuming* and be on our way.

Then we parse the "header" section of the payload:

```
byte[] reservedData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(96);
byte[] signature = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2);
byte[] tsPropertyCount = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2);

string signatureValue = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(signature);
ushort tsPropertyCountValue = BitConverter.ToUInt16(tsPropertyCount, 0);
```

We don't care about `reservedData` so we can safely ignore it.

We however should care about `signature`: when converted to a Unicode string it should *always* be equal to the string "P", if it's not there's something wrong with the data. I really encourage you to throw a nice InvalidDataException if `signatureValue` is not equal to "P".

`tsPropertyCount` tells us how many properties we have to read, so we convert it to a ushort.

Then we need to read as many property as `tsPropertyCountValue` tells us:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tsPropertyCountValue; i++)
```

We don't really care for `i`, we only need to execute the content of the loop as many times as required.

```
byte[] nameLength = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2);
byte[] valueLength = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2);
byte[] type = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2);

ushort nameLengthValue = BitConverter.ToUInt16(nameLength, 0);
ushort valueLengthValue = BitConverter.ToUInt16(valueLength, 0);
ushort typeValue = BitConverter.ToUInt16(type, 0);

byte[] propName = binaryReader.ReadBytes(nameLengthValue);
byte[] propValue = binaryReader.ReadBytes(valueLengthValue);

string propNameValue = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(propName);
byte[] propValueValue = GetPropValueValue(propValue);
```

As previously stated we need to obtain `nameLengthValue` and `valueLengthValue` to know the length of the name of the property and the length of the value of the property.

`typeValue`, similarly to `signature`, *should* always be equal to `0x01`, even if the documentation is not really clear about it. Personally I'd throw an InvalidDataException if it's not equal to `0x01`.

We convert the value of `propName` back to a Unicode string to get the name of the property, and then the magic happens.

`byte[] propValueValue = GetPropValueValue(propValue);` is where the magic happens: `GetPropValueValue` decodes the doubly-ASCII-encoded value back to its native form:

```
private static byte[] GetPropValueValue(byte[] propValue)
{
  // Since the encoding algorithm doubles the space used, we halve it.
  var propValueValue = new byte[propValue.Length / 2];

  // Parse the encoded bytes two-by-two, since the encoding algorithm transforms
  // one bytes in two bytes we need to read two of them to obtain the original one.
  for (var j = 0; j < propValue.Length; j = j + 2)
  {
    // Compute the two halves (nibbles) of the original byte from the values of the
    // two encoded bytes. Each encoded bytes is actually an hexadecimal character,
    // so each encoded byte can only have a value between 48 and 57 ('0' to '9')
    // or between 97 and 102 ('a' to 'f'). Yes, it's an utter waste of space.
    var highNibble = HexToInt(propValue[j]);
    var lowNibble = HexToInt(propValue[j + 1]);

    // Recreate the original byte from the two nibbles.
    propValueValue[j / 2] = (byte) (highNibble << 4 | lowNibble);
  }

  return propValueValue;
}
```

To convert the hexadecimal byte back to its value there's a simple helper function:

```
private static int HexToInt(byte value)
{
  if ('0' <= value && value <= '9')
  {
    return value - '0';
  }

  if ('a' <= value && value <= 'f')
  {
    return value - 'a' + 10;
  }

  if ('A' <= value && value <= 'F')
  {
    return value - 'A' + 10;
  }

  throw new Exception("Invalid character.");
}
```

Why are we using int instead of byte when rebuilding the original byte?

Because the output of the subtraction performed inside `HexToInt` produces an int, and the bitshift and bitmask operations output is an int, so converting the two nibbles to byte is a waste of resources, they would be converted back to int in the next instruction.

> Thanks to [CodesInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445517) for his [hex-to-byte conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333437/91696) and black magic.

Now we only have to convert the value to the correct type and assign it to the correct property of our class, we can do that with a simple if-else chain:

```
if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxCfgPresent), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxCfgPresent = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxCfgFlags1), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxCfgFlags1 = (CtxCfgFlags1) BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxCallBack), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxCallBack = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxKeyboardLayout), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxKeyboardLayout = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxNwLogonServer), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxNwLogonServer = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxMaxConnectionTime), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxMaxConnectionTime = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxMaxDisconnectionTime), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxMaxDisconnectionTime = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxMaxIdleTime), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxMaxIdleTime = BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxShadow), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxShadow = (CtxShadow) BitConverter.ToUInt32(propValueValue, 0);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxMinEncryptionLevel), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxMinEncryptionLevel = propValueValue[0];
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxWfHomeDir), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxWfHomeDir = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propValueValue, 0, propValueValue.Length - 1);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxWfHomeDirDrive), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxWfHomeDirDrive = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propValueValue, 0, propValueValue.Length - 1);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxInitialProgram), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxInitialProgram = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propValueValue, 0, propValueValue.Length - 1);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxWfProfilePath), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxWfProfilePath = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propValueValue, 0, propValueValue.Length - 1);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxWorkDirectory), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxWorkDirectory = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propValueValue, 0, propValueValue.Length - 1);
}
else if (string.Equals(propNameValue, nameof(UserParameters.CtxCallbackNumber), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  userParameters.CtxCallbackNumber = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propValueValue, 0, propValueValue.Length - 1);
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("Unsupported property.");
}
```

And we're done!

> **Nota bene:** The `CtxCfgPresent` property is special, it should *always* be present and its value *should* always be equal to `0xB00B1E55` (yes, I know, very funny). If it's missing or its value is not equal to `0xB00B1E55` then the value of the attribute is corrupted and should not be used, personally I suggest throwing our friendly InvalidDataException in such cases.

For those who managed to stay with me until the end, I've published a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104161935/https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/30473a6261e34a518bf5433702bde041) on GitHub (I can't include the full code here due to character count limitations).

Comment: This looks way too broad, genius! +1.

Comment: Thank you so much for your c# implementation! Did you ever figure out what the "Undefined" hex values map to in the USERCONFIG struct? It seems to be the case that Undefined4 and Undefined7 pops up for most users in AD, but I have no idea what it signifies. Have had no luck googling it, either :)

Comment: @Grisungen no, I never found out what these values mean.

Comment: Fantastic answer +1